# Is there any way to use Named Ranges in Google Sheets to replace the column letters in formulas for readability?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have formulas that reference values on other sheets such as `=OtherSheet!M2`

For readability, is there a way to substitute "M" with something else so I can remember what data is being pulled in without going back to the other sheet and seeing what data column M contains?

The closest feature I am aware of is Named Ranges, but I don’t see how I would rewrite the formula above using it.

Comment: [What to do when a user receives a good answer to their question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Create a named range for `OtherSheet!M2` that is descriptive to you (e.g., `ClientName`), then set the formula to `=ClientName`.

Comment: The problem is that M3, M4, M5, etc would also be "ClientNames". I'm hoping to have ClientName (row 2), ClientName (row 3), etc

Comment: Based on your posted example (which is all we have), what I suggested fits and will work. Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know your setup, data, data types, data ranges, overall purpose, etc. So you are asking us to *imagine* an awful lot here. I will say that I myself do not have a clear picture of what you are trying to do. I suggest you share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) and choose one *specific* example of where you'd like to use a named range and what that *specific* formula should return.